# Mocking an instance method in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm testing a ruby class using Rspec in Rails

```
class VolumeAnalysis
```

That class has a method that makes calls to active record

```
returned_volumes
```

This method grabs an array of items from active record and returns something like:

```
[
    <struct volumeAnalysis::Entry date="2019-12-03", volume=0.3864511633501078e4, predicted=0.143488366498922e3>,
    <struct volumeAnalysis::Entry date="2019-12-04", volume=0.3699056933789016e4, predicted=0.165454699712062e3>,
....
....
....
.... ]
```

Other methods in the class which I wish to test depend on this method, how do mock this methods return value?

Comment: Try something like this: `allow(volume_analysis).to receive(:returned_volumes) { and_then_create_your_entry_structs_here }` - more information in this link here - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs - it should be very straightforward

Comment: What's the cleanest way of mocking the structs?

Comment: no need to mock the structs - just create them as you would create them normally - that would be the fastest and cleanest way

Comment: Sorry, I mean what is the syntax for adding the struct items to ````receive(:returned_volumes) { and_then_create_your_entry_structs_here }```` how do I add the struct to ````and_then_create_your_entry_structs_here````?

Comment: were you successful in mocking?

Comment: actually thought I was but no, do I need to do ````[VolumeAnalysis::Entry.new(DateTime.current, 0.123, 0.123), VolumeAnalysis::Entry.new(DateTime.current, 0.123, 0.123),VolumeAnalysis::Entry.new(DateTime.current, 0.123, 0.123),VolumeAnalysis::Entry.new(DateTime.current, 0.123, 0.123)]```` for each new struct?

Comment: the above creates an array of structs - not a single one. Also, I have assumed you have defined your struct in the VolumeAnalysis class - have you defined it there?

Comment: yes the struct is defined in the VolumeAnalysis class, and I need an array of structs or something where the objects can be accessed like object.date, object.volume, object.predicted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203562/discussion-between-bkspurgeon-and-falko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
allow(volume_analysis).to receive(:returned_volumes) { and_then_create_your_entry_structs_here }

def and_then_create_your_entry_structs_here
  [VolumeAnalysis::Entry.new(DateTime.current, 0.123, 0.123)] 
  # this is quick and dirty - you'll have to create the Entry objects properly
end
```